# Adjust heap function causes index range assertion to fail

Tags: c, heap

I've built an adjust heap function, but my `assert(position < array->size)` is failing and I can't figure out why.

```
void adjustHeap(DynamicArray* heap, int max, int pos, compareFunction compare)
{
    // FIXME: implement
    int leftChild = 2 * pos + 1;
    int rightChild = 2 * pos + 2;
    int idxSmallest = indexSmallest(heap, leftChild, rightChild);
    if(rightChild < max) { /* we have two children */
        if(dyGet(heap, pos) > dyGet(heap, idxSmallest)) {
            dySwap(heap,pos,idxSmallest);
            adjustHeap(heap, max, idxSmallest, compare);
        }
    }
    else if (leftChild < max) { /* we have one child */
        if(dyGet(heap, pos) > dyGet(heap, leftChild)) {
            dySwap(heap,pos,leftChild);
            adjustHeap(heap, max, leftChild, compare);
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

My `dyGet()` function:

```
TYPE dyGet(DynamicArray* array, int position)
{
    assert(position < array->size);
    return array->data[position];
}
```

My `assert(position < array->size)` is failing in `dyGet()` using the following test:

```
void testAdjustHeap(CuTest* test)
{
    const int n = 100;
    Task* tasks = createTasks(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        DynamicArray* heap = dyNew(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            dyAdd(heap, &tasks[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            dyPut(heap, &tasks[rand() % n], 0);
            adjustHeap(heap, dySize(heap) - 1, 0, taskCompare);
            assertHeapProperty(test, heap);
        }
        dyDelete(heap);
    }
    free(tasks);
}
```

'indexSmallest' function:

```
int indexSmallest(struct DynamicArray * v, int i, int j) { /* return index of smallest element */
    if(i < j) {
        return i;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'failing'?

Comment: The assertion isn't passing...ie: `position` is greater than `array->size`.  This would cause an index out of range error if I didn't have the assertion, but either way it doesn't work.

Comment: You either need to use a debugger (or add some printfs to the code), so you can see the values of your variables when the assert fails. BTW, I have a feeling that the problem is in `indexSmallest`, but you haven't shown that code. See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does you indexSmallest look like?

Comment: I added in indexSmallest for you.

Comment: try printing out position and size in..... TYPE dyGet(DynamicArray* array, int position)
{
    assert(position < array->size);
    return array->data[position];
}  What numbers do you get?

Comment: Essential parts of the program are missing, e. g. `dyAdd()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of passing your array into index smallest? The function looks wrong. i is always going to be less than j no matter what based on

```
int leftChild = 2 * pos + 1;
int rightChild = 2 * pos + 2;
```

if youre talking about the actual data contained at those children, then it might look different.
perhaps passing in

```
indexSmallest(v->data[leftChild], v->data[rightChild])
```

I hope that helps